# What is the /usr/bin/dir binary on linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ls

I noticed I have a `/usr/bin/dir` which mostly behaves like `/usr/bin/ls`. I assumed first it was a convenience for people coming from DOS/Windows. I assumed this would just be a softlink to `ls`, but my first surprise was that this is a separate binary:

```
$ ls -la /usr/bin/dir /usr/bin/ls
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 125736 Feb  7  2022 /usr/bin/dir
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 125736 Feb  7  2022 /usr/bin/ls
```

My second surprise is that these files are not the same:

```
$ md5sum /usr/bin/dir /usr/bin/ls
997a2268f6d68d4b3f309dce17b39261  /usr/bin/dir
c12515ea5d425b198c1e44d6470588af  /usr/bin/ls
```

This is on:

```
$ uname -a
Linux ip-172-31-63-158 6.2.0-1017-aws #17~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Nov 17 21:19:35 UTC 2023 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is explained in the GNU Coreutils documentation.
Unfortunately the shared manpage for `ls` & `dir` does not state this clearly.

> [10.2 `dir`: Briefly list directory contents](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/dir-invocation.html)
>
> `dir` is equivalent to `ls -C -b`; that is, by default files are listed in columns, sorted vertically, and special characters are represented by backslash escape sequences.
>
> See [`ls`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/ls-invocation.html).

Documentation for the options `-C` & `-b` is also there.

> [10.1.4 General output formatting](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/General-output-formatting.html)
>
> `-C`
> `--format=vertical`
> List files in columns, sorted vertically, with no other information. This is the default for `ls` if standard output is a terminal. It is always the default for the `dir` program. GNU `ls` uses variable width columns to display as many files as possible in the fewest lines.

> [10.1.6 Formatting the file names](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Formatting-the-file-names.html)
>
> `-b`
> `--escape`
> `--quoting-style=escape`
> Quote nongraphic characters in file names using alphabetic and octal backslash sequences like those used in C.